# Store.EntryID Different Depending on Session Logon Method

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2007, outlook-redemption

I am using Redemption objects in Access VBA to access Outlook.

The `DefaultStore.EntryID` is different depending on which Session `logon` method I use.

Here's my code:

```
Dim oSession As New Redemption.RDOSession
oSession.Logon
Debug.Print oSession.Stores.DefaultStore.EntryID
oSession.Logoff
oSession.LogonExchangeMailbox ("MyADUsername"), "mail.server.com"
Debug.Print oSession.Stores.DefaultStore.EntryID
oSession.Logoff
Set oSession = Nothing
```

My first `Debug.Print` returns a string that is about 336 characters long. The second `Debug.Print` returns a different string (*with some of the same characters*) that is about 76 characters long.

What might I be doing wrong or misunderstanding here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All MAPI entry ids must be treated as black boxes. Multiple entry ids can refer to the same object, so the entry ids should never be compared directly. Use RDOSession.CompareEntryIDs for that.